<AG-GRID>EXCEL export can export WYSIWYG
 this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel(this.getParams());
  getParams: () => ExcelExportParams = () => {    
    return {
      columnKeys: this.columnKeys,
      prependContent: this.getRowsPrependContent(), 
      author: '', 
      sheetName: this.tabTitle,
      fileName: this.tabTitle, 
  
       processCellCallback: params => {
       }}}

ry EXCEL export, how can the same effect as Csv export, export table display, without the need for separate processing
Problems caused by not handling manually:

If leading zeros exist, zeros are deleted from EXCEL
2. similar to the following custom code does not take effect, exported the original code, rather than display the value
valueFormatter: params => { return !params.node?.isRowPinned() && params.value ? this.lookupValue(this.departmentMappings, params.value) : null; }


<AG-GRID>EXCEL export can export WYSIWYG，
The table shows the same as the exported one
